# Powershell: deploying dacpac to SQL Server 2012 has error 'Unable to connect to master or target server'

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I can deploy dacpac to SQL Server 2012 using `sqlpackage.exe`. The SQL Server has Windows authentication.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /a:Publish /sf:"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\yyy\Database1.dacpac" /tdn:test-dacpac1 /TargetServerName:.\sql12
```

However it failed with PowerShell. The PowerShell script:

```
$dacpacFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\yyy\Database1.dacpac"    $databaseServerName  = ".\sql12"
$targetDatabaseName = "test-dacpac1"
$upgradeExisting = "True"

#http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac-with-powershell/
add-type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"

#service
$dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices "server=$databaseServerName"

#dacpac
$dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacpacFileName)

#options
$options = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacDeployOptions
$options.GenerateSmartDefaults="True"

#deploy
$dacService.Deploy($dp, $targetDatabaseName, $upgradeExisting, $options) 

#error
$error[0]|format-list -force
```

The error:

> Exception: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Deploy" with "4" argument(s): "Could not deploy package."
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package.
>
> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException: Unable to connect to master or target server 'test-dacpac1'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'test-dacpac1'.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: I suspect you need to instantiate the DacServices object with a proper connection string (i.e. something like "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=true").

Comment: Either that or something's off in the parameters. The fact that it's trying to connect to a server named "test-dacpac1" would seem to indicate that a parameter could be off somewhere.

Comment: restart to get it working. still dont know why.